# How to pass the chebox value from a parent to parent to child and after set it into the vuex store VueJS/Vuex

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Hi everyone i have a big trouble i need to modify the value of checkbox from parent to another parent to child , is not this difficulty i know but i'm at the start and after spent 2 days for this i can't try anything else , now i'll add all the code the child is named "UICheckbox" and i pass it to "ToDoListItem" and this last is passed to "ToDoList" , and every Todos is an in an array into "store.js"

**UICheckbox**

```
    <template>
    <div class="checkbox-container">
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        :id="id"
        :v-model="localTodo"
      >
      <label :for="id">
        <p class="font-bold">{{ text }}</p>
      </label>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: [
    "id",
    "value",
    "text"
  ],
  data() {
    return {
      localTodo: this.value
    }
  },
  watch: {
    localTodo:{
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.$emit("change", newVal)
      },
      deep: true, 
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**ToDoListItem**

```
    <template>
  <div class="flex flex-row w-full my-2">
    <UICheckbox 
      :v-model="localTodo.checked" 
      :id="todo.id" 
      :text="todo.text"
      @change="localTodo.cheked = $event"
    />
    <delete-button :todo="todo" />
  </div>
</template>
```

**ToDoList**

```
        <to-do-list-item 
          :todo="todo"  
          @click="changeChecked(todo)" 
          @change="todo.checked = $event"
        />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of copy and pasting your entire code, that way, it'll make it easier for the potential answerers to focus on the issue at hand.

Comment: You can simply use an event bus - use a watcher for the checkbox and every time it changes, emit an event to the event bus. Each component which is interested in those events will subscribe for them on the event bus.